# How to separate elements from an image

Tags: image-processing, image

I have this file that will always have a white background and I would like to separate the elements into separate files, but I don't know which function to use.

This is the file:

[image]

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/WydPS.png"]
ColorQuantize[img, 20, Dithering -> False]
```

I would just like to extract the images as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If this question is very simple or is a duplicate, I would like a guidance

I have Mathematica version 11 available

Comment: This might be helpful [How to make a list of images out of one image without using the lasso selection tool?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130615/8070)

Answer (score 4):

```
Values @ Rest @ ComponentMeasurements[img, "MaskedImage"]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
Values @ ComponentMeasurements[ColorQuantize[RemoveBackground[img], 5, 
     Dithering -> False], "Image"]
```

[image]

Comment: I tested it with images with a white background, but with shadows in the images and it didn't give the same result. It worked well with colors without a gradient. I imagined something like changing the white background of an alpha channel.